# how to add UIView on Camera?

Tags: iphone

I want to add one view on to the camera.I have use below code for this.But not working.

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; //or album  
[picker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
[self presentModalViewController:picker  animated:NO];
```

How it is possible?Anything is wrong in my code?

Comment: do you want to add effects onto the camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`picker.cameraOverlayView` is `nil` by default, so instead you want to do `picker.cameraOverlayView = self.view` instead of the way you have it.